# How to access friends email details via graph api

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the friends "email address" using graph api ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook friends email FQL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5114784/facebook-friends-email-fql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Facebook allow a user to give my app access to their friends email addresses?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8190675/does-facebook-allow-a-user-to-give-my-app-access-to-their-friends-email-addresse)

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure, but as a measure of spam prevention I don't think Facebook makes this accessible without the permission of your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have them authorize your app.  Otherwise, nope not possible.  Make it so your app is so cool and entertaining that they cannot resist giving up such personal information as their email to partake of your app.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow apps to access **friends** emails

Comment: That's exactly what I just said.  If the user's friend authorizes the app with `email` permissions, otherwise not possible.  I never said a friend's email was accessible without that friend authorizing access to their email.  Please read the permissions page.

Answer (score 0):

yes and no. If you take a friend's "username" and append @facebook.com, you have an email address that you can use to send a message. However, this message will not arrive as an ordinary facebook message in the receivers "Inbox", but it will be sorted into the "Other" Messaging folder.